# Wiki markup with templates

Tags: formatting, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have a template where I would like to include a variable `{{{1}}}`, but I also want the text that will be placed there to be in `<code>{{{1}}}</code>` tags.

But in that case wiki just ignores `{{{1}}}` and treates it as a normal text.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a template that contained just `<code>{{{1}}}</code>`, then I called it with `{{Name of the template|foo}}`. This generated the HTML `<code>foo</code>`, as expected.